# Creating a regex pattern to match "string/uuid" pattern

Tags: regex, uuid, jsonschema

A string like this would match:

```
"test/00b46e01-3994-4ac2-939e-2d5052a65961"
```

Or like this

```
"anotherword/58628d3f-becf-4f54-bdea-336ca9247145"
```

The regex for uuid (v4) I have is `"^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$"` for my JSON schema (i.e. my JSON object holds a uuid property), but now I want to incorporate the 'string/' in front of this pattern as well.

Comment: Try adding `[a-zA-Z]+/` after `^` if you want to match ASCII letters followed with `/`.

Comment: Or just add (after `^`) `[^/]+/` to match any 1+ chars other than `/` and then a `/`.

Comment: Awesome! You could add that as an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) like `[^/]+` to match 1 or more chars other than `/` and `/` at the start of the pattern after `^`:

```
"^[^/]+/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$"
  ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6jTqOV/1).

If you also want to match a string that has no chars before `/`, replace the `+` quantifier (that matches 1 or more occurrences) with `*` (0 or more occurrences).